# zend framework check if column exist in a resultset

Tags: zend-framework, resultset, exists

I have this query for example:

```
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $query_Group = $dbAdapter->select();
    $query_Group->from(array('FI' => 'request_field'),
                       array('*'));


    $resultRows = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($query_Group);
```

Ok, now how can I know if inside $resultRows there is the column "Label" for example?
I know I can do that:

```
    foreach($resultRowsas $key => $Field)
    {
         if(isset($Field['Label'])
         { ....  }
    }
```

But if is possible I want it to know without loop it....

It is possible?

Thanks again....

Answer (score 0):

`$Field['Label']` will always be set. It may be empty, but will always be set!
if you want all records where the value is NULL, change your query appropriately

Comment: Thanks for your answer...   I think I confuse you with my example...   Try to figure out...   I have this:   $resultRows = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($query_Group);    My question is:   How can I know witch column are in this resulset: $resultRows ?    For example I need somenthing like:  columnexist($resultRows, 'Label')...   Is there a function like that?   Thanks again...

Comment: quote the answer to @dinopmi!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to know whether a given column exists in the table. In that case, you might call the `describeTable()` method for this.

You can see a description in the [Zend_Db_Adapter documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.list-describe).

If the column is defined in the table schema, then you need to query for an appropriate value, like NULL, as @JellyBelly says. In this case, his answer is what you need.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer...   But I didn't understand how to check it...   Try to figure out...   I have this:   $resultRows = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($query_Group);    My question is:   How can I know witch column are in this resulset: $resultRows ?    For example I need somenthing like:  columnexist($resultRows, 'Label')...   Is there a function like that?   Thanks again...

Comment: All the rows in the resulting rowset must have the same columns, in that case. You just need to get the first one and check which columns it contains:
    $firstRow = $resultRows->first();
    $firstRowArray = $firstRow->toArray();
    if (isset($firstRowArray['Label'])) {
       ... etc...
    }